# Conversion of image annotation formats into tfrecords for tensorflow object detection api

Tags: tensorflow, annotations, tensorflow-datasets, object-detection-api, tfrecord

Seeking help regarding image annotation formats for object detection API.

> - **Foreknow:**

As, we know there are two annotation formats for images, Pascal VOC and COCO formats. Both have their own specification here's the main difference between both:

**Pascal VOC:**

1. Stores annotation in .xml file format.
2. Bounding box format [x-top-left, y-top-left, x-bottom-right, y-bottom-right]
3. Create separate xml annotation file for each image in the dataset.

**COCO:**

1. Stores annotation in .json file format.
2. Bounding box format [x-top-left, y-top-left, width, height].
3. Create one annotation file for each training, testing and validation.

> - **Current-issue:**

I have two dataset to deal and this is how they are annotated.

**Dataset-1:**

- File format: Pascal VOC(.xml)
- Bounding box format: COCO.
- File creation: As in Pascal VOC(separate xml annotation file for each image in the dataset).

**Dataset-2:**

- File format: Pascal VOC(.xml)
- Bounding box format: COCO.
- File creation: As in COCO(Create one annotation file for each training, testing and validation)

The thing that I am not able to get pass through is which format(Pascal VOC or COCO) should I follow to convert my annotations into Tfrecords(.xml to .records) as use can see the annotations of dataset aren't purely belong to any of one format.

For instance, in [this link](https://github.com/sglvladi/TensorFlowObjectDetectionTutorial/blob/master/docs/source/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py) the author wrote a script to convert .xml into .records but here it is dealing with pure pascal VOC format.

And in [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py) they are dealing with pure COCO annotation formats.

*Which path should I follow as I am standing in the middle of both formats?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which path should I follow as I am standing in the middle of both formats?

1. Use Pascal VOC format for conversion of .xml into .records.
2. Make the following changes in a `create_tf_example` function of [this link](https://github.com/sglvladi/TensorFlowObjectDetectionTutorial/blob/master/docs/source/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py)

   ```
   for index, row in group.TextLine.iterrows():
   xmin.append(row['X']/imgwidth)
   xmax.append((row['X']+row['Width'])/imgwidth)
   ymin.append(row['Y']/imgheight)
   ymax.append((row['Y']+row['Height'])/imgheight)
   classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
   classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))'
   ```

In case where you have X, Y, Width, Height in your .xml annotations instead of xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax.